# Why does Pseudorapidity distribution have two peaks?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, collision, large-hadron-collider, quark-gluon-plasma

I found plots(fig2) that state that it is the sum of two gaussian distributions, but I am not able to understand its physical significance. Any help would be appreciated.[PS Why does rapidity not have two peaks?]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because rapidity and pseudo-rapidity are related by a Jacobian. The Jacobian is such that for heavier mass it gives a dip to the plot. Hence for massless particles(photon), we won't see any dip, and pseudo-rapidity and rapidity will be the same.

PS I'll update my post when I get a better understanding of the matter.
Reference: C.Y Wong Introduction To High-energy Heavy-ion Collision; Chapter 1

Comment: I am yet to find a physical reason